# what is the correct configuration of RadAjaxManager - this issue is in ralationship with UpdatePanel !

Tags: asp.net, ajax, visual-studio-2010, updatepanel, radajaxmanager

At first look at the below aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm4.aspx.cs" Inherits="Amlak.WebForm4" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
            <AjaxSettings>
                <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadComboBox1">
                    <UpdatedControls>
                        <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="CheckBox1" UpdatePanelRenderMode="Inline" />
                    </UpdatedControls>
                </telerik:AjaxSetting>
            </AjaxSettings>
        </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
        <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" AppendDataBoundItems="True"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <Items>
                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="1" Value="1" />
                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="2" Value="2" />
                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="3" Value="3" />
                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="4" Value="4" />
            </Items>
        </telerik:RadComboBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged"
            Text="Check Me" TextAlign="Left" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My code behind is like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Amlak
{
    public partial class WebForm4 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void RadComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (RadComboBox1.SelectedItem.Value == "2")
            {
                CheckBox1.Checked = true;
            }
            else
            {
                CheckBox1.Checked = false;
            }

        }

        protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (CheckBox1.Checked)
            {
                TextBox1.Text = "text";
            }
            else
            {
                TextBox1.Text = "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My goals:

1. I want to force `RadComboBox1` to work in AJAX mode and change the CheckBox1.Checked by defined conditions in code behind. -> do not want postback for this.
2. I want to force `CheckBox1` to work in PostBack mode and change the `TextBox1.text` by defined conditions in code behind. -> I want postback for this.

In this scenario -> `RadComboBox1` works fine
but I don't know why `OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged"` does not fire when we change check of `CheckBox1`! (because we added it as update of `RadComboBox1` In `RadAjaxManager1`).

---

My questions:

Should I add `RadComboBox1` as update Of `RadComboBox1` or not?  However it works fine without adding this.

If we add `ChechBox1` To `RadAjaxManager1` like below:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm4.aspx.cs" Inherits="Amlak.WebForm4" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
            <AjaxSettings>
                <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadComboBox1">
                    <UpdatedControls>
                        <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="CheckBox1" UpdatePanelRenderMode="Inline" />
                    </UpdatedControls>
                </telerik:AjaxSetting>
                <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="CheckBox1">
                    <UpdatedControls>
                        <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="TextBox1" />
                    </UpdatedControls>
                </telerik:AjaxSetting>
            </AjaxSettings>
        </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
        <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" AppendDataBoundItems="True"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <Items>
                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="1" Value="1" />
                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="2" Value="2" />
                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="3" Value="3" />
                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="4" Value="4" />
            </Items>
        </telerik:RadComboBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged"
            Text="Check Me" TextAlign="Left" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

So it works fine in AJAX mode, but I want to force `CheckBox1` to work in PostBack!
How can I fix this issue?

Should I add `TextBox1` as update of `RadComboBox1` in `RadAjaxManager` or not?

Thanks for attention to my question.
best regards

Comment: i have 2 questions from a manager in this community : 1-is any body here / 2-why Notify Email does Not work for me (i checked that notify checkbox)? (where can i ask such this questions in this community?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of the OnRequestStart even of the RadAjaxManager to disable Ajax functionality for specific requests. Here's an updated version of your code that works as you requested:

```
<div>
    <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
        <AjaxSettings>
            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadComboBox1">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl
                        ControlID="CheckBox1"
                        UpdatePanelRenderMode="Inline" />
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl
                        ControlID="TextBox1"
                        UpdatePanelRenderMode="Inline" />
                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="CheckBox1">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl
                        ControlID="TextBox1"
                        UpdatePanelRenderMode="Inline" />
                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        </AjaxSettings>
        <ClientEvents OnRequestStart="onAjaxRequestStart" />
    </telerik:RadAjaxManager>

    <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox1" runat="server"
        AutoPostBack="True"
        AppendDataBoundItems="True"
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <Items>
            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="1" Value="1" />
            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="2" Value="2" />
            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="3" Value="3" />
            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="4" Value="4" />
        </Items>
    </telerik:RadComboBox>

    <br />
    <br />

    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server"
        AutoPostBack="True"
        OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged"
        Text="Check Me"
        TextAlign="Left" />

    <br />
    <br />

    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" />

    <telerik:RadCodeBlock runat="server">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function onAjaxRequestStart(s, e) {
                var target = e.get_eventTarget(),
                    checkBoxId = '<%= CheckBox1.ClientID %>';
                if (target === checkBoxId) {
                    e.set_enableAjax(false);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </telerik:RadCodeBlock>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Current RadAjax Limitations](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/ajxlimitations.html) says,

> RadAjaxManager setting will not ajaxify the button...
>   ...when having no updated controls

So, you probably will have to do something like:

```
<UpdatedControls>
               <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="ChechBox1" />
</UpdatedControls>
```